# Finding a stochastic differential equation as limit of a discrete stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes

I stumbled upon a problem that seems simple but I cannot tackle it. Let $X_n$ be a discrete process defined by the following algorithm.

Choose $X_0\in[0,1]$, set $\kappa>0$ small enough and
$X_{n+1}=X_n+\kappa(I_n-X_n)$
with $I_n=1$ with probability $X_n$ and $I_n=0$ with probability $1-X_n$.

In other words the $X_n$ decreases with probability $1-X_n$ by $\kappa X_n$ and increases with probability $X_n$ by $\kappa(I_n-X_n)$ so $E[X_{n+1}]=X_n$.

The point is that $\kappa$ can be arbitrarily small so we can take its limit to $0$ while decreasing linearly the time step. This naturally should give an SDE (in this case I would expect it to be non-linear). So my question is how can one find this SDE or the PDE that gives the probability density.

I should add that for short times it looks like a random walk (which is expected I guess) with the variance being proportional to $\kappa t X_0(1-X_0)$, with $t$ small. However since $X_n\in[0,1]$, $1$ is an upper bound for the variance.

Edit: It is not $\kappa t X_0(1-X_0)$, it is $\kappa^2 t^2 X_0(1-X_0)$

Comment: Of course the PDE that gives the probability density is the Fokker–Planck equation.

Comment: This question has also been asked at math.overflow (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/84231). I voted to close the question there, but I think it suits this site fine.

Comment: I'll also add my comment which I posted on mathoverflow here. "I think this is quite standard stuff, discretely approximating an SDE by a binary tree. Taking a time step size of $\kappa^2$ will converge weakly to a solution to the SDE $dX=\sqrt{X(1−X)}\,dW$. So, I'm not really sure that this is research level, and is just a special case of the general method of discretely approximating SDEs. I think Roger's and Williams book (vol 2) should cover this, although maybe not in this precise form."

Comment: ...by which I mean, the weak compactness method for SDEs described in Rogers and Williams together with uniqueness for the SDE $dX=\sqrt{X(1-X)}\,dW$ should work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sketch of how you might approach this. Let
$$
  \xi_j = \frac{\kappa(I_{j-1} - X_{j-1})}
    {\sqrt{X_{j-1}(1 - X_{j-1})}}.
  $$
The two "hard" results that must be proven are: (1) For each $t$,
$$
  \lim_{\kappa\to0} E\big[\max\{|\xi_j|: 1 \le j
    \le \lfloor\kappa^{-2}t\rfloor\}\big] = 0,
  $$
and (2) for each $t$,
$$
  \sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor\kappa^{-2}t\rfloor} \xi_j^2 \to t,
  $$
in probability as $\kappa\to0$. The rest of the proof would then be the following "soft" argument based on general theory.

First, let $W^\kappa(t)=\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor\kappa^{-2}t\rfloor} \xi_j$. Using the two results above, one can use the martingale central limit theorem (Theorem 7.1.4 in [Ethier & Kurtz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047176986X)) to prove that $W^\kappa\Rightarrow W$, where $W$ is a standard Brownian motion.

Next, we take the difference equation which defines the sequence $\{X_n\}$ and rewrite it as an integral equation. More specifically, if we define $X^\kappa(t)=X_{\lfloor\kappa^{-2}t\rfloor}$, then we may write
$$
  (1) \qquad X^\kappa(t) = X_0 + \int_0^t \sqrt{X^\kappa(s-)(1 - X^\kappa(s-))}\,dW^\kappa(s).
  $$
There is nothing deep here, just a change of notation, really.

Finally, we use Theorem 5.4 in [Kurtz & Protter](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-19/issue-3/Weak-Limit-Theorems-for-Stochastic-Integrals-and-Stochastic-Differential-Equations/10.1214/aop/1176990334.full) to prove that $(X_0,X^\kappa,W^\kappa) \Rightarrow(X_0,X,W)$, where $X$ is the unique strong solution to $dX=\sqrt{X(1-X)}\,dW$, $X(0)=X_0$.

A watered-down version of Theorem 5.4 in Kurtz & Protter is available as Theorem 2.3 in [these lecture notes](http://math.swansonsite.com/instructional/skor_lemmas.pdf). This version is sufficient for your purposes, and it may be easier to digest. Also, to use this theorem, you must show that, for every version of $(X_0,W)$, the limiting SDE has a unique strong solution for all time. This follows, for example, from Proposition 5.2.13, Theorem 5.5.4, and Corollary 5.3.23 in [Karatzas & Shreve](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387976558).

Comment: Thank you very much for your feed back, it was extremely helpful. I surely need quite a bit of time to work this out. However I have a question on intuition. What is the intuition behind the definition of $\xi_J$? Is this something standard that I miss?

Comment: Once you identify the limiting SDE, then you know you want Equation (1) to hold. The definition of $\xi_j$ is chosen precisely so that Equation (1) works out.